# Conflict between ProGuard implementation and R8 with VS2019

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, proguard

Currently in my `Xamarin.Android` application I am using ProGuard optimizer with Visual Studio 2017.

I am wondering what will be the impact of **`R8`** when I will update my Visual Studio to 2019. For that do I need to remove `proguard.cfg` from android project or it will automatically update.

What will be the changes?

Comment: You will remove all the existing progaurd configuration and replace it with r8's configuration https://medium.com/@hakimgulamali88/a-deep-dive-into-androids-d8-dexer-and-r8-shrinker-with-xamarin-ca66e00b1c8d

Comment: my pleasure, get back to me if you have queries